# RewriteCond - change images name

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi people I'm here to ask about RewriteCond / rewrite

I have a request for a images on my server lets say the request is /images/peoples-place.png
the word "place" is in the link is a changing variable but the images on the server is named peoples.png so how should I rewrite this is? is it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(images/peoples(.+?)\.png)$
RewriteRule ^images/peoples\.png [R=301,L]$
```

Hope you can help thx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something such as this should work:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[^/]+(.*)/images/(.+)-([^\.]+)(\.png) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/images/%2%4 [R=302,L]
```

<sub>http://example.com/images/something-else.png ⌇ http://example.com/images/something.png</sub>

[image]

Comment: Thank you that was nice :) btw what a nice explanation !